# XSLT and XPATH: Not able to Read Certain Attributes

Tags: xslt, attributes

```
<field type="math" size="12"  unitText="%" unitPos="back"/>
```

I am able to select "type" and "12" from their respective fields but I cannot do the same for unitText and unitPos. Any ideas why?

Below is what I'm using to print type and size.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@size"/>
```

I am entering the "field" tag with this line

```
<xsl:template match="field" mode="all">
```

Thanks for any assistance. Been banging my head against the wall for awhile. :P

Comment: You probably need to show more of your XSLT. The template/match looks fine, although it will only be invoked when you're in mode "all". The `<xsl:value-of select="@size"/>` is correct and the analogous code should work for @unitText and @unitPos. So without more XSLT context it will be difficult to guess what's going wrong.

Comment: Seing as those two might have case-sensitivity issues, you might want to elaborate what exact software you're using with the xslt transformation.

Comment: We're using Struts 1.1. Not sure if this the info you're looking for. ^_^

Comment: If you want more specific help you'll probably need to show more of the XSLT stylesheet, e.g. the content of the template that matches field, and the code that applies that template (in mode="all").

Comment: This has always frustated me. I think I've included all that I've needed to but I understand that its not always enough. But it's annoying to frequently get the request "post whole code snippet".

That's not usually a possibility. This is work-related code and I can't have it posted in whole chunks on the net. 

/rant

Comment: "and the code that applies that template (in mode="all")"
The first line is what you requested. :P That's all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="field">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),': ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With input:

```
<field type="math" size="12"  unitText="%" unitPos="back"/>
```

Output:

```
type: math
size: 12
unitText: %
unitPos: back
```

Comment: Turns out it's not case sensitive comparisons. :(

Comment: @bobber205: Yes, that is basic in XML, whether you are dealing with XPath, CSS or Emacscript